# Get name of invoking function in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, invoke

I have the following code:

```
function foo () {
    $sb = (Get-Command bar -CommandType Function).ScriptBlock
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb
}

function bar () {
    demo
}

function demo () {
    Write-Host $((Get-PSCallStack)[0].Command)
    Write-Host $((Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command)
}

foo
```

The result of this is:

```
foo
demo
```

What I want to get instead is:

```
bar
demo
```

The problem seems to be that within the function foo I am calling the function bar by using the Invoke-Command cmdlet and that powershell sees this as the calling function of demo. By my understanding the function bar is calling demo, not foo.

I can not figure out why powershell behaves that way and how to get to the point where powershell returns to me the function name "bar".
Even my idea to "fool" powershell by saying:

```
function bar () {
    $sb = (Get-Command demo -CommandType Function).ScriptBlock
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb
}
```

did not lead to any success regarding "bar".
I am at the point where I am desperately calling out for your help.

Comment: If you want actually want `bar` in the call stack then why are you shoving the definition into a scriptblock rather than just calling it? e.g. `function foo { bar }`

Comment: exact. You never invoked `bar`. You invoked a ScriptBlock saved in `$sb` (taken from `bar`)

Comment: That is exactly the problem I did not see! Thanks a lot your answers - highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the question comments, it sounds like the original problem was solved by simplifying the approach. But I think I stumbled on an answer to the question, itself. I changed `.Command` to `.FunctionName` in the demo code:

```
function foo () {
    $sb = (Get-Command bar -CommandType Function).ScriptBlock
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb
}

function bar () {
    demo
}

function demo () {
    Write-Host $((Get-PSCallStack)[0].FunctionName)
    Write-Host $((Get-PSCallStack)[1].FunctionName)
}

foo
```

And output now shows `bar` (instead of `foo`) as desired:

```
demo
bar
```